# Нужно ответы с сервера заменять готовы решениями из массива

Tags: javascript, jquery

С сервера приходят ответы (result) в виде статуса:
active,stop,pause и тд.
Нужно по заранее готовому массиву заменять их
Т.е так:

```
active - активно
stop - стоп 
и тд.
```

Как это в коде должно выглядеть?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как должно не знаю, но может выглядеть так:

```js
const map = {ru: {
  active: 'активно',
  stop: 'стоп',
}};

const locale = 'ru';

const someRequest = () => Promise.resolve({result: 'stop'});

const localizeRequest = (req) => req()
  .then(res => {
    ///Object.keys(res).forEach(key => {...})
    if (map[locale][res.result]) res.result = map[locale][res.result];
    return res;
  });

localizeRequest(someRequest)
    .then(res => console.log(res));
```

Comment: Я плохо достаточно разбираюсь,а в какой части кода окончательный результат,который можно заключить в переменную?

Comment: Ну вот то, что выводится в консоль (`console.log(res)`) и есть локализованный результат. Главное, не забывайте про [асинхронность](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/554290/176064)

Comment: Спасио за ответ

Answer (score 1):

Вот, попробуй данный код!

```js
const translate = {active:"активно",stop:"стоп"} // Словарь RU-EN
var res = "active";
for(const otv in translate){
    if(res === otv){
        res = {};
        res[otv] = translate[otv]
    }
}
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
let dictObj = {"active":"активно","stop":"стоп"};

let resultKey = "stop";
console.log("Ответ сервера - ", resultKey);

let my_event = dictObj[resultKey];
console.log("Выполняемое действие - ", my_event);
```

Comment: Спасибо на ответ)